# Postgres.app pdo_pgsql pgsql installed but php couldn't find module. MAC OS X

Tags: php, macos, postgresql, pdo, php-pgsql

I have problem with Postgres.app.
Postgres.app is running without problems.

In my `phpinfo()` I can see.

```
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlite, pgsql
```

If I run commat `php -m` I can see:

```
...
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
```

Everything seems to be installed and prepared. 
But If I run my project, It says.

```
could not find driver
```

I've installed pgsql and pdo_pgsql by following link https://alistairphillips.com/apple/osx/php-pdo-pgsql/

PS: I also have

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

Comment: try brew reinstall php55 --with-pgsql [other-options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After install new OS X El Capitan I have to:
Please note that I've installed http://postgresapp.com/ I highly recommend this.

- Install PHP5 from http://php-osx.liip.ch/
- Download PHP source packages (for my version) from http://php.net/downloads.php
- Unpack sources and do following:

  - `cd php-{version}/ext/pdo_pgsql`
  - `phpize`
  - `./configure --with-pdo-pgsql="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4"`
  - `sudo make && make install`
- Install pgsql:

  - `cd php-{version}/ext/pgsql`
  - `phpize`
  - `./configure --with-pgsql="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4"`
  - `sudo make && make install`

Or I've modified one script I've found. You can download and use it from https://gist.github.com/FilipLukac/b460b233857a65e1342a

- Set up `PHP_VERSION` variable
- Set up `PHP_INI` variable (`php.ini` file location path)
- Run `./install.sh`

And then restart apache `sudo apachectl -k restart`

Comment: On sudo make && make install, I get the error: `fatal error: 'pdo/php_pdo_error.h' file not found #include "pdo/php_pdo_error.h"`. I downloaded php 5.6.1

Comment: Fixed the previous error by changing the `pgsqldriver.c`'s `#include "pdo/php_pdo_error.h"` to `#include "../pdo/php_pdo_error.h"`. The next error is the "rootless" feature of El Capitan: `Operation not permitted
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1`